# where is Adobe Flash Prefrences?

Tags: firefox, video, flash, adobe, mate

I use Mate, on both debian and Ubuntu, periodically I like to use a video chat website that uses flash. I find that if the site doesn't have permissions to flash camera and mic setting prior to visiting the site, when i try to configure camera and mic settings via the flash object, the plugin crashes, and I need to log out of the site, and thus reload flash. In Debian, Mate, under Settings>Preferences>Adobe Flash Player I can grant permissions to sites prior to going to the site. Doing so seems to prevent flash from hanging up when I try to stream video.

So, how can I get an Adobe Flash preferences option, akin to what is in Debian, in Ubunutu?
here an image of what I am talking about.   [image]

For Clarification:
When I try to use the on-line global settings menu, it hangs. Then I must close the tab, and reopen it, because it gets stuck right there.  Also, [this link](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html), is hella old, macro-media hasn't owned flash since 2005.

I get the same behavior when i try to use the online global settings menu in debian. It only works when I can set the site preferences prior to going to the site. 
This is why I am interested in finding the Prefrences menu for Adobe flash in ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install flash?

Comment: I used the software center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it would be nice to have something in the preferences menu, but I found `flash-player-properties` in terminal. that launches the configuration menu in debian, when I go home in a few hours, I will test it in Ubuntu.

::Home sweet Home::

ok, well its wasn't in there by default as part of the package which installed via the software center, and sudo apt-get install flash-player-properties didn't work either.

There were no additional packages in the software center for adobe flash (even with all sources enabled), I decided to reinstall from source. In Debian, I can't recall how I installed flash. It might have been from source.

Anyhow, I downloaded the package from https://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/

,extracted it, and cd'd into the source dir.
as soon as I entered `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr` I had the adobe flash preferences in my system preferences.

the command `flash-player-properties`  now works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your settings [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)

Comment: Please, do not delete your answer when I say that, no, I cannot.When I try to use the on-line global settings menu, it hangs. Then I must close the tab, and reopen it, because it gets stuck right there. Badhi.zazen posted the same response earlier, but deleted it.  Also, that link, is hella old, macro-media hasn't owned flash since 2005.

Comment: @j0h: Sorry. It works for me.

Comment: does the online gloabl setting program leave an error log any place? I am interested to know what is going on.

Comment: @j0h: I don't know.